# Cannot sink kafka topic into influxdb

Tags: json, apache-kafka, influxdb, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

My Topic Schema looks like this,

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "optional": false
  },
  "payload": "{...}"
}
```

I am trying to sink this into an Influx DB instance with this configuration,

```
curl -X PUT \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{
               "connector.class":"io.confluent.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector",
                    "tasks.max": "1",
                    "topics" : "mongo-sink-json.tractor.job",
                    "influxdb.url": "http://10.100.87.169:8086",
                    "influxdb.db": "mongo-sink",
                    "infuxdb.password": "password",
                    "influxdb.username": "user",
                    "measurement.name.format": "${topic}",
                    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
                    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
                    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
          }' \
```

But I get this error in Kafka Connect logs,

> ERROR
> WorkerSinkTask{id=influx_sink_json_job-0} Task threw an uncaught and
> unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover
> until manually restarted. Error: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
> java.util.Map (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
> java.util.Map     at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.extractPointTags(InfluxDBWriter.java:288)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.getPointTags(InfluxDBWriter.java:266)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.getKey(InfluxDBWriter.java:329)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.getBatch(InfluxDBWriter.java:149)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.write(InfluxDBWriter.java:126)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.InfluxDBSinkTask.put(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:40)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [2020-09-25 20:46:53,519]
> ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=influx_sink_json_job-0} Task threw an uncaught
> and unrecoverable exception
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting
> WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.    at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:568)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
> java.util.Map     at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.extractPointTags(InfluxDBWriter.java:288)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.getPointTags(InfluxDBWriter.java:266)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.getKey(InfluxDBWriter.java:329)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.getBatch(InfluxDBWriter.java:149)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter.write(InfluxDBWriter.java:126)
> at
> io.confluent.influxdb.sink.InfluxDBSinkTask.put(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:40)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)

Anyone has any ideas?
I used the similar config to sink the same topic in MongoDB and it works perfectly.

Should I use any other influxdb sink connector or fall onto using avro serialization or this is unrelated?

Comment: are you using schema registry for this topic? taking a stab in the dark, i'd say your converters are not correct.

Comment: Hi, the issue is nested json which needs to be flattened in order to be stored in influxdb as a measurement. I was able to store the payload in influx, but I need to separate the message for influx to be able to store them as key:value pairs.